# Firestore new database - How do I backup

Tags: backup, google-cloud-firestore

Does the google firestore database service provides a backup?
If so, how do I backup the database and how do I restore in case of an error?

Comment: It's a beta product at the moment and does not yet offer any backup tool. So you'll have to write on yourself.

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/5r3xeda07ek

Comment: It's now GA since a few years, but still there is no backup option. This makes me skeptical of using Firestore in production apps.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Update**: It is now possible to backup and restore Firebase Firestore using Cloud Firestore managed export and import service

You do it by:

1. [Create a Cloud Storage bucket for your project](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) - Make sure it's a regional in us-central1 or 2 / multi regional type of bucket
2. Set up **gcloud** for your project using `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`

**EXPORT**

**Export all** by calling
`gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`
Or **Export a specific collection** using
`gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME] --collection-ids='[COLLECTION_ID_1]','[COLLECTION_ID_2]'`

**IMPORT**

**Import all** by calling
`gcloud firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/`
where [BUCKET_NAME] and [EXPORT_PREFIX] point to the location of your export files. For example - `gcloud firestore import gs://exports-bucket/2017-05-25T23:54:39_76544/`

**Import a specific collection** by calling:
`gcloud firestore import --collection-ids='[COLLECTION_ID_1]','[COLLECTION_ID_2]' gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/`

Full instructions are available here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: Is there a way to backup database automatically every X hours? Basically how to I hook it up with a cron job?

Comment: @codefx take a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Comment: I wrapped this into a npm package to be deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions. Check my answer out for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56618618/3763626

Comment: This is now available in gcloud beta components. Documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import.

Comment: @codefx you can write a bash script to execute the gcloud command, then schedule it from your crontab on Ubuntu. Just be sure to set the PATH variable at the top of your crontab to allow it to execute gcloud commands.

Comment: As per what @RDRR mentioned, please update your answer to prevent confusion for new visitors.

Comment: There's a page in the docs with explicit instructions for scheduling periodic exports of Firestore data https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

Answer (score 33):

Update July 2018: Cloud Firestore now supports managed import and export of data. See the documentation for more details:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

---

*[Googler here]* No, right now we do not offer a managed backup or import/export service.  This is something we will definitely offer in the future, we just did not get it ready for the initial Beta release.

The best way to back up right now is to write your own script using our Java/Python/Node.js/Go server SDKs, it should be fairly straightforward to download all documents from each collection and write them back if you need to.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for commenting - Bonus points If someone could share their code (Node.js for extra bonus :) )

Comment: i have run into rate limits trying to restore large data sets. is there a timeline for the official backup and restore tool that ideally doesn't require an api request for each document write operation?

Comment: @ForrestLyman Have you tried [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)?

Comment: @hakatashi Firebase now support it natively. See my answer above.

Comment: Is it possible to do daily backups, like available in Firebase RT DB?
the firebase guide attached here describe how  to do single backup,I would like to configure daily backup.

Comment: @ykorach see this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

Comment: Any news on supporting this natively, like the way Firebase Realtime Database does?

Comment: The backup counts as reads. I'm seeing 500+600% read count increase when scheduling it. There must be a better way of doing this.. it's expensive.

Answer (score 18):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup

Is a tool that has been created to do just this.

(I did not create it, just adding it here as people will find this question)

Comment: That tool doesn't seem to have any functionality to restore the Firestore DB though

Answer (score 7):

##### Local backups

1. [firestore-import-export](https://github.com/jloosli/node-firestore-import-export)

> This is the one I use for "one-off", local backups, and what I generally recommend. (most straight-forward if you want a single JSON file)

2. [firestore-backup-restore](https://github.com/willhlaw/node-firestore-backup-restore)

> Drawbacks:
>
> 1. Hasn't been updated in a long time.

---

Additional options: (not recommended)

3. [python-firebase-admin-firestore-backup](https://github.com/RobinManoli/python-firebase-admin-firestore-backup)

> Drawbacks:
>
> 1. Backup only; cannot restore from the backups it creates.
> 2. Hasn't been updated in a long time.

4. [firestore-backup](https://github.com/steadyequipment/node-firestore-backup)

> Drawbacks:
>
> 1. Backup only; cannot restore from the backups it creates.

##### Cloud backups

1. The official [gcloud backup commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).

> Drawbacks:
>
> 1. The backup files are difficult/infeasible to parse. (update: how to [convert to a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60350712/2441655))
> 2. You have to set up the [gcloud cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud). (update: or use the [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) to run the commands)
> 3. It doesn't backup locally; instead, it backs up to the cloud, which [you can then download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59567734/2441655). (could also be considered an advantage, depending on what you want)

Note that for the gcloud backup commands, you have some options on how to schedule them to run automatically. A few options are [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53357765/2441655).

2. Using the [Database export function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data) in Google Cloud console.

> Similar advantages/disadvantages as the previous option, except avoids needing to use a CLI, so arguably easier.
>
> And, as for approach 1, if you want the backup to be human-readable, you'll need to [convert it to json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60350712/2441655).

Answer (score 6):

I am using the following work-around in order to have daily firestore backups:

I installed this globally: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup-restore

I have a cron job that looks like this:

```
0 12 * * *  cd ~/my/backup/script/folder && ./backup-script.sh
```

And my backup-script.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ~/.bash_profile

export PATH=/usr/local/bin/

dt=$(/bin/date '+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S');
echo "starting backup for $dt"
firestore-backup-restore -a ~/path/to/account/credentials/file.json -B ./backups/"$dt"
```

Answer (score 6):

I've written a tool that traverses the collections/documents of the database and exports everything into a single json file. Plus, it will import the same structure as well (helpful for cloning/moving Firestore databases). It's published as an NPM package. Feel free to try it and give some feedback.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and created a small npm package which allows you to create a scheduled backup with Cloud Functions. It uses the new import/export feature of Firestore.

```
const firestoreBackup = require('simple-firestore-backup')
exports.firestore_backup = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun(firestoreBackup.createBackupHandler())
```

Checkout the full [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-firestore-backup) on how to set it up, it's super simple!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using **Python 2**.

Fork it on https://github.com/RobinManoli/python-firebase-admin-firestore-backup

First install and setup Firebase Admin Python SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Then install it in your python environment:

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

Install the Firestore module:

```
pip install google-cloud-core
pip install google-cloud-firestore
```

(from [ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264536/importerror-failed-to-import-the-cloud-firestore-library-for-python))

Python Code

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import json

cred = credentials.Certificate('xxxxx-adminsdk-xxxxx-xxxxxxx.json') # from firebase project settings
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com'
})

db = firebase_admin.firestore.client()

# add your collections manually
collection_names = ['myFirstCollection', 'mySecondCollection']
collections = dict()
dict4json = dict()
n_documents = 0

for collection in collection_names:
    collections[collection] = db.collection(collection).get()
    dict4json[collection] = {}
    for document in collections[collection]:
        docdict = document.to_dict()
        dict4json[collection][document.id] = docdict
        n_documents += 1

jsonfromdict = json.dumps(dict4json)

path_filename = "/mypath/databases/firestore.json"
print "Downloaded %d collections, %d documents and now writing %d json characters to %s" % ( len(collection_names), n_documents, len(jsonfromdict), path_filename )
with open(path_filename, 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(jsonfromdict)
```

Comment: There is already a build in native solution for it that can backup / restore from  the command line.

Comment: What is that built in native solution? Some people might not want to mess around with a cloud storage bucket, especially if they want to process the data. Don't see the reason for a downvote. In my case when I came here I would have preferred a python solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Android Java code for get backup easily for any fire store data collection

First use this method to read the collection data and store in it to serialized file in the mobile device storage

```
private void readCollection(){
        ServerSide.db.collection("Collection_name")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            HashMap alldata = new HashMap();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                alldata.put(document.getId(),document.getData());
//                                ServerSide.db.collection("A_Sentences_test").document(document.getId())
//                                        .set(document.getData());
                            }
                            try {
                                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("filename.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                                os.writeObject(alldata);
                                os.close();
                                fos.close();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("filename.txt");
                                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                                HashMap ad = (HashMap) is.readObject();
                                is.close();
                                fis.close();
                                Log.w("All data",ad+" ");

                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Log.w("errrrrrrrr",e+"");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Colllllllllll", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

After that you can check the logcat whether the data is serialized correctly. and here is the restore code

```
private void writeData(){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("filename.txt");
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            HashMap ad = (HashMap) is.readObject();
            is.close();
            fis.close();
            for (Object s : ad.keySet()){
                ServerSide.db.collection("Collection_name").document(s.toString())
                        .set(ad.get(s));
            }
            Log.w("ddddddddd",ad+" ");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, projects are nice but I have some concerns about the backup.

1-For blaze plan users (free) official solution is off-limit.

2-Since Free users have 50k read quota per day that limit could be a problem in live and large databases.

3-As far as I examined most of the projects does not have a time limit or so, downloading same data every time it is run.

4-Wouldn't it be better to save collections as folders and every document as seperate file and and fetch only updated documents and replace file directly.

I will probably implement my own solution but just wondering your thoughts :)