# ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Trying to integrate Google firestore API at python server

```
...
  File "/home/daffolap-355/repos/subscriptions/appvendor/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure '
ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
```

I get this error here:

`from firebase_admin import credentials, auth, firestore`

I installed the `firebase-admin` module:

`pip install --upgrade -t libs firebase-admin`

And run the app

`dev_appserver app.yaml`

Comment: Try installing `google-cloud-firestore` instead of (or in addition to?) `firebase-admin`, as per the error message.

Comment: Sometimes the dev appserver has issues loading `google.*` modules from the local `lib/` directory. If the modules are indeed installed correctly, try something like the solution described [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/169#issuecomment-315417916).

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Cloud Firestore requires `grpc`.

```
pip install grpcio
```

However, there are additional steps depending on your OS. Check out 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/python/grpcio

Comment: September 2022 - still had the same problem with a clean install, `pip install grpcio` is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!! Definitely check out the GitHub Link.

Answer (score 6):

**To solve the "google-cloud-firestore" module error do this:**

- pip install google-cloud-core
- pip install google-cloud-firestore

**And then import like this:**

- import os
- import firebase_admin
- from firebase_admin import
  credentials
- from google.cloud import firestore
- from firebase_admin
  import firestore

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. **Try uninstalling and re-installing google-cloud-firestore**

1. Uninstall "google-cloud-firestore" using pip

   ```
      pip uninstall google-cloud-firestore
   ```
2. Re-install it using pip again

   ```
      pip install google-cloud-firestore
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue when installing firebase_admin library on windows. 
The solution was to downgrade protobuf library to 3.6.0.

```
pip install protobuf==3.6
```