# ImportError: cannot import name 'firestore'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm doing a dataflow streaming app that would write in firestore, when I run on DirectRunner it works, but when I run on DataflowRunner it doesn't works. what is the error? my `requirements.txt` is:

```
apache-beam[gcp,test]==2.19.0
google-cloud-pubsub
google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0
```

the row of code that throws the exeption is:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
db = firestore.Client(project=project)
```

Comment: I found a similar thread, is the answer on here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264536/importerror-failed-to-import-the-cloud-firestore-library-for-python

Comment: yes, but nothing. it doesn't work. i see that if the import put in the function that uses firestore, it start, instead if I put it on top of module, it doesn't start. could it is an help for you?

Comment: Could you share the code where you are doing the import please?

Comment: yes, I have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the Dataflow FAQ, there are few ways to handle this

1. Use `import` statement inside the function definition
2. Set `save_main_session` to True in the Pipeline Options
3. Define the dependencies and organize your folder structure appropriately with requirements.txt and setup.py files

More details can be found here - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors