# AWS lambda Python functions gives error to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module, but is already installed 2022

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda

Hi I have an AWS Lambda in Python 3.9 (now regenerated in AWS functions console),I have installed in my aws folder:

```
pip install --target . firebase-admin
```

And finally I have implemented my Python AWS lambda, and upload to AWS lambda as ZIP file a package. When I tried to execute my testing in the Python Lambda, this gives me this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the \"google-cloud-firestore\" module.",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I also installed in my local directory the grpcio module, before to upload ZIP file in AWS function console, with this command:

```
pip install --target . grpcio
```

But the same error is displayed when I execute a test in AWS cloud function.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the \"google-cloud-firestore\" module.", ....
}
```

What can I do to solve this error? & made available google-cloud-firestore works fine in my AWS Lambda Python?

Thanks

Comment: Do not zip the folder, just zip the contents of it alone. Ex: cd lambda_code/ and then zip * and upload the zip

Comment: Yes! Inside the folder! I zip * all files & folders and this ZIP I uploaded to AWS lambda function, but always gives me the same error "Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264536/importerror-failed-to-import-the-cloud-firestore-library-for-python)

Comment: No! This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264536/importerror-failed-to-import-the-cloud-firestore-library-for-python does not work in my AWS.  Always says  Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the \"google-cloud-firestore\" module."

Comment: did you ever find a solution, currently encountering the same issue.